# When to use the formal definition of a limit for showing convergence?

Tags: real-analysis

The question states: Is the sequence ($x_n$)$_{n=1}^{\infty}$ with:
           \begin{align}
   x_n:=\frac{4n^2+sin(\frac{1}{(n^{13})})-17n}{2n^2+cos(n)}\end{align}    for n$\mathcal{E}\mathbb{N}$ convergent? If so determine its limit?

My confusion is that I don't know in what scenario I should be using the formal definition versus just showing the limit exists for $x_n$. In this scenario would showing the limit exists justify convergence or would I need to use the formal definition to do so? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Any time you're (properly) showing a sequence converges, you're using the formal definition behind the scenes, even if it doesn't look like it. If you use a theorem of the form "If X, then the sequence converges" you don't need to formally state the definition of limit because it comes with the theorem.

Comment: How formal your argument should be depends on your audience. In this case an informal (but in principle formalizable) argument is easy and a formal $\epsilon - N$ proof would be tedious.

Comment: By $n^13$, did you mean $3n$ or $n^{13}$ (`n^{13}`)?

Comment: @J.G. sorry it should be $(n^{13})$, just edited it

Comment: You may also want to edit "n$\mathcal{E}\mathcal{N}$", though I'm sure what it should have been.

Comment: "just showing the limit exists for $x_n$": but how exactly do you plan to do this ???

Comment: @YvesDaoust I planned on showing that 4, $\frac{sin(\frac{1}{(n^{13})})}{n^2}$, $\frac{17}{n}$, 2, and $\frac{cos(n)}{n^2}$ all converge using the formal definition of a limit and therefore $x_n$ converges and the limit exists

Comment: @TomRiddle: as long as you use proven existence theorems (that in fact derive from the formal definition), you are fine. E.g. the limit of a sum of two terms that converge exists.

Comment: The mathjax for $n \in \Bbb N$ is `n \in \Bbb N` (or `\mathbb N`, but I always prefer the short form myself).